# Connect to Django test database

Tags: django, django-database, django-tests

Is there a way to connect to django test database using `connections`?

I have tried
`cursor = connections['test_name_of_main_db'].cursor()`
and also specified the test db name in settings but I still receive errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "/home/tets/4d/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 176, in ensure_defaults


  conn = self.databases[alias]
KeyError: 'auto_tests'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):



     File "/home/tets/healthware_server/component/medical/tests.py", line 72, in test_model_observation
cursor = connections['auto_tests'].cursor()
     File "/home/tets/4d/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 208, in __getitem__ self.ensure_defaults(alias)
     File "/home/tets/4d/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 178, in ensure_defaults
raise ConnectionDoesNotExist("The connection %s doesn't exist" % alias)

django.db.utils.ConnectionDoesNotExist: The connection auto_tests doesn't exist
```

Comment: You want to connect during the tests or before/after the tests?

Comment: durng(will be nice in setUp method), i just need to create the object and not to dispacted singnal from signals.py( don't want to comment signals )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database):

> The default test database names are created by prepending `test_` to the value of each NAME in DATABASES.

But in your stacktrace the error says:

```
django.db.utils.ConnectionDoesNotExist: The connection auto_tests doesn't exist
```

Are you sure you are using the right alias? According to the error, it is looking for a database named `auto_tests`.

As another debugging step, you could print all the aliases during the test to see which ones are available

```
for alias in connections:
    print(alias)
```

Of course, you could also try to use the default database and see if that works for you during the tests:

```
# note that it is 'connection' and not 'connections'
from django.db import connection
cursor = connection.cursor()
```

Comment: will try, the `auto_tests` was add to settings.pay as test db name.

Comment: [Note the exception](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEST_NAME): "If the default value (`None`) is used with the SQLite database engine, the tests will use a memory resident database. For all other database engines the test database will use the name `'test_' + DATABASE_NAME`."